# Calculating a variable diversity in SPSS

Tags: spss

Is there any way to calculate diversity of a specified variable in a data set using SPSS?
I need to calculate education diversity among my respondents. 
education has been measured in 4 different levels
Thanks

Comment: Is this a statistical question or a programming question?

Comment: what is variable diversity ?

Comment: I think It is a programming question.

Comment: Please explain what your data looks like (what variables contain what data - preferably post an example) and what calculation you are trying to perform (preferably with the expected results of your example)

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you're not being sufficiently clear in what measure(s) you want to calcluate. Many SPSS procedures offer various measures of variation, such as the range, variance and standard deviation, etc. It seems you're thinking of these four levels as perhaps an ordinal scale rather than an interval scale, in which case many of these standard measures may not be too useful.

The following SPSS MATRIX commands take a variable named "N" containing the ordered counts in the categories and compute a measure known as an ordinal dispersion index (copy and paste them into a syntax window, set up appropriate data, and in the syntax window, select Run>All):

```
matrix.
get counts /var=N
 /missing=omit.
compute totaln=msum(counts).
compute k=nrow(counts).
compute fo=make(k,1,0).
compute fo(1)=counts(1).
loop i=2 to k.
compute fo(i)=fo(i-1)+counts(i).
end loop.
compute fo=fo/totaln.
compute odi=0.
loop i=1 to k-1.
compute odi=odi+(fo(i)-.5)**2.
end loop.
compute odi=1-(4*odi)/(k-1).
do if odi<0.
compute odi=0.
end if.
do if odi>1.
compute odi=1.
end if.
print odi.
end matrix.
```

If you have your data structured as required but with a different variable name, just change the "N" at the end of the second line to the name of the variable.

Your data probably aren't in the form of the just the counts, but the AGGREGATE procedure can easily produce a dataset with this structure. In the menus choose Data>Aggregate, choose the education variable as a break variable, check the box for Number of cases, change the variable name there to just "N", select the option to create a new dataset containing only the aggregated variables, give the dataset a name, and click OK.

The new dataset will contain only the education variable and the N variable with the counts in each category, as required by the MATRIX commands.